# How to get array of arrays with conditions from an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array containing hashes, like this:

```
[
    {:id => 1, :week => 1, :year => 2014},
    {:id => 2, :week => 2, :year => 2014},
    {:id => 1, :week => 1, :year => 2015},
    {:id => 2, :week => 5, :year => 2015},
]
```

What i need is a array of arrays, containing each two values:
The first value is a hash from the first array with year 2014, the second is a hash from the first array with year 2015, if it has the same week and id as the first hash.

If there is not hash with equal id and week from 2015, then the second value has to be nil, vice versa the first value is nil.

For the array above, the new array should look like:

```
[
    [{:id => 1, :week => 1, :year => 2014}, {:id => 1, :week => 1, :year => 2015}],
    [{:id => 2, :week => 2, :year => 2014}, nil],
    [nil, {:id => 2, :week => 5, :year => 2015}],
]
```

-e-
my approach:

```
result = []
all_ids.each do |id|
  all_weeks.each do |week|
    v1 = array.select{ |v| v.id == id && v.week == week && v.year == 2014}        
    v2 = array.select{ |v| v.id == id && v.week == week && v.year == 2015}
    v1 = v1.length == 1 ? v1.first : nil
    v2 = v2.length == 1 ? v1.first : nil
    result << [v1, v2]
  end

end
```

this doesn't seem to be very efficient as i have to iterate the array multiple times

Comment: `a.group_by { |el| [el[:id], el[:week]] }` might be a good way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group_by` to separate your hashes by week and id, then you just need to pad out the arrays that don't have two values:

```
array.group_by { |v| [v[:id], v[:week]] }.values.each do |a|
  a.insert(2015 - a[0][:year], nil) if a.length == 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that is intended to emphasize readability (seriously).

**Code**

```
    def convert(arr)
      a14 = arr.select { |h| h[:year] == 2014 }
      a15 = arr - a14
      arr = a14.map do |h14|
        i15 = a15.index { |h15| h14[:id]==h15[:id] && h14[:week]==h15[:week] }
        [ h14, i15.nil? ? nil : a15.delete_at(i15) ]
      end
      arr.concat([nil].product(a15)) if a15.any?
    end
```

If the value of `:year` can be other than `2014` or `2015`, replace `a15 = arr - a14` with:

```
a15 = arr.select { |h| h[:year] == 2015 }
```

Note that `a15.delete_at(i15)` serves a dual-function: it removes the value at index `i15` from `a15` and returns that value for inclusion in the tuple.

**Example**

```
arr = [ {:id => 1, :week => 1, :year => 2014},
        {:id => 2, :week => 2, :year => 2014},
        {:id => 1, :week => 1, :year => 2015},
        {:id => 2, :week => 5, :year => 2015} ]

convert(arr)
  #=> [[{:id=>1, :week=>1, :year=>2014}, {:id=>1, :week=>1, :year=>2015}],
  #    [{:id=>2, :week=>2, :year=>2014}, nil],
  #    [nil, {:id=>2, :week=>5, :year=>2015}]]
```